# Why is my image height not changing?

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript and am using the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>javascript learning</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function resizeRock() {
            document.getElementById("rockImage").style.height = (document.body.clientHeight - 100) * 0.5;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="resizeRock();">
    <!--ROCK-->
    <div id="image">
        <img src="http://outdoordesignbylucas.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/1-10-11-triangular-rock.jpg" id="rockImage" onclick="touchRock();" style="cursor: pointer;" />
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

This code is not resizing the image, however the following code is working as expected:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>iRock - The Virtual Pet Rock</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      function resizeRock() {
        document.getElementById("rockImage").style.height = (document.body.clientHeight - 100) * 0.5;
      }


    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="resizeRock();">
    <div style="margin-top:100px; text-align:center">
      <img id="rockImage" src="http://outdoordesignbylucas.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/1-10-11-triangular-rock.jpg" alt="iRock" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="touchRock();" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am breaking my head over this. The code is the same, the top (not working) is what I wrote - the bottom is from a book. What am I missing?

Comment: You're resizing the div. Why do you expect the img's size to change?

Comment: @Juhana He's not resizing the div. `document.getElementById("rockImage").style.height` will change the height of the rock, not the div.

Comment: This might work: Change `document.getElementById("rockImage").style.height = (document.body.clientHeight - 100) * 0.5;` to `document.getElementById("rockImage").style.height = *(document.body.clientHeight - 100) * 0.5) + 'px';`. Thiss will give your number a unit.

Comment: @JoshuaDwire Ah, I see. (The image's id was out of view in the first code.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your style a unit.

Change this line:

```
document.getElementById("rockImage").style.height = (document.body.clientHeight - 100) * 0.5;
```

To this:

```
document.getElementById("rockImage").style.height = ((document.body.clientHeight - 100) * 0.5) + 'px';
```

Thiss will tell the browser that you are setting the height in px, instead of percent, pt, em, etc.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/BvrTD/) / [Full Screen Result](http://fiddle.jshell.net/jdwire/BvrTD/show/light/)

Comment: I don't know how your code is different from the book's code though. Maybe the book's code doesn't work either?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the DOCTYPE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This put your document into standard mode. Add this css:

```
html
{
height: 100%
}
body
{
height: 100%
}
```

Adding `"px"` to the end of the statement will solve the problem because in standard mode you need to state the unit explicitly.
Alternatively you can delete `<!DOCTYPE html>`